# Windows 10 - Where is the windows calculator?

Tags: windows-10

I am trying to create a shortcut for the windows 10 default calculator.
I have tried to use open file location from the task explorer but it won't let me access the location.

Comment: Windows key and type: calculator

Comment: It's likely located under C:\Program Files\WindowsApps but going into such folder will require changing folders permission settings which I am not in the mood of personally doing.

Comment: My personal preference for calculator is to open it once manually then right click the taskbar icon and pin it to the taskbar... Then I move it all the way to the left end of the task bar next to "start" where it stays forever.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Right-click where you want to create the shortcut.
2. Select *New → Shortcut*.
3. In the *Type the location of item* field enter `calc`.
4. In the next step choose any name you like for the shortcut.

Answer (score 6):

To create a calculator shortcut on the Windows 10 desktop!

> Click on an empty space on the Windows 10 desktop, right Mouse-Button. And select "New", "shortcut"
>   the location, or the full path of the Win10 calculator: C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe 
>   Click the Button "Next".
>    Please enter the name for the Desktop-Shortcut, you can calc.exe leave or enter calculator.
>   [Click for more](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-10&faq=19)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know where the application really is, I found it at C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe in Windows 11 V. 10.0.22621. No need to change folder permissions to access. For my need (setting up a keyboard special-function key to open the calculator) it was better to have a directory to the actual executable than a shortcut cluttering a random folder.